# Javascript can't understand russian letters

Tags: javascript

```
var letter1 = "ю"
```

This will return some obscure character. Does anybody have a way to add Russian characters to javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a unicode character: `var letter1 = '\u044E'`

Check more at http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0400-04FF

Comment: Follow the url in my answer

Comment: Authoring the JS (or HTML) file in UTF-8 and making sure it is being parsed accordingly should also work.